# Can you map the open unit disk conformally onto $\{ z: 0 < |z| < 1 \}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, analytic-functions

I only find that is not possible from the punctured disk to the unit disk, but in the other direction is possible or not ? If not, counter example, if yes please provide the mapping.

This is problem 15 from section 3 chapter 3, functions of complex variables Conway book.

Comment: If you could, the inverse function would go back in the other direction, which you know can't happen.

Comment: I have the solution to this problem, so your answer is not correct.

Comment: Usually a conformal map of $U$ onto $V$ means a holomorphic bijection of $U$ onto $V.$

Comment: My mapping is not bijective, then is a problem of definition. For my Conway book conformal is angle preserving mapping that satisfies that the absolute value of the limit of the differential quotient exists for all values on it's domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\textbf{Solution:}$

Let $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1 \}$ and $D^{*} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0 < |z| < 1 \}$.

Consider the Mobius transformation that takes $D$ to the right half plane

$
z_1 = \displaystyle\frac{1 + z}{1 - z}
$

then by a rotation, we can obtain the left half plane

$
z_2 = -z_1
$

Finally, the left half plane can be mapped conformally to $D^{*}$ by the exponential transformation

$
z_3 = e^{z_2}
$

Hence, the desired conformal map is $f: D \to D^{*}$

$
\boxed{
f(z) = \exp\{-\displaystyle\frac{1+z}{1 - z}\}
}
$